# TypeScript - Why allow assign string to a number

Tags: typescript

My question is why allow the following if TypeScript is for type safely? Is there a flag for tsconfig to stop this?

```
let strNum: any = "2";
let numTest: number;
numTest = strNum;
console.log(`Type of number is: ${typeof numTest}`) 
// Output number is: string
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're setting your string to the `any` type:

```
let strNum: any = "2";
```

If you did just:

```
let strNum = "2";
```

TypeScript will complain and say "type `string` is not assignable to type `number`".

---

Also, when you log `typeof numTest`, that is JavaScript running, not TypeScript. TypeScript only knows anything about your code at compile time. Once you have running code TypeScript is out of the picture.